# Renaming mulitple files linux

Tags: linux, rename

I Have mulitple files like

```
test-20050231-description.jpg
test-20050301-description.jpg
```

and  i wanted to rename them to the format

```
test-2005-02-31-description.jpg
test-2005-03-01-description.jpg
```

I tried the rename command for that but couldnt get a solution.

Would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: What did you try? What was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Perl rename utility:

```
rename -n 's/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3/' test-*-description.jpg
```

Remove `-n` if the output looks as expected.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Had some trouble to find the the right regex for that.

Answer (score 0):

assuming they are always in the same format you can do substring with loop:

```
cd /wanted/path/
for i in *.jpg; do mv "$i" "${i:0:9}-${i:9:2}-${i:11:2}${i:13}" ;done
```

Answer (score -1):

What command did you type exactly as the rename command? AFAIK the best way to rename a file is to use the `mv` command. Have you tried:

```
mv test-20050231-description.jpg test-2005-02-31-description.jpg
```

Another possibility I can think of is that you may be moving files you don't have permission to move. If you own the machine you're working on you can try typing `sudo` before the `mv` command.

Comment: I knew that that one also, but it is not very practical with multiple files at a time, but thank you too for the quick answer.